# Marie program to identify prime numbers

Tags: marie

Write a MARIE program that accepts an integer from the user, and if it is a prime number the program will output 1, otherwise, the program will output 0. Examples:

If the user input is 17, the output would be 1

If the user input is 15, the output would be 0

can please some help me to develop this to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code :

```
Org 0
Input
Store A
Store Val2

Output
Subt one
jump testNeg

Loop, Load A
Subt Value
Skipcond 400
jump div
jump prime

div, Load Val2
Store A
if, Load A
Skipcond 400
jump else
jump prime
else, Skipcond 800
Jump Endif
Then, Load A
Subt Value
Store A
Jump if
Endif, Load Value
Add one
Store Value
jump div

testNeg, Skipcond 000
jump testZero
jump nonPrime
testZero, Skipcond 400
jump Loop
jump nonPrime
nonPrime, Load zero
Output
Halt
prime, Load Val2
Subt Value
Skipcond 400
jump nonPrime
Load one
Output
Halt

A, DEC 0
one, DEC 1
zero, DEC 0

Value, DEC 2
Val2, DEC 0
```